# Can I plug a computer directly into an wireless router that is extending a wireless network?

Tags: wireless-networking, airport, airport-express, airport-extreme

My current wireless network consists of an Airport extreme plugged into my cable modem via ethernet and an airport express that is extending the wireless network (wirelessly). I have an extra airport extreme as well as a computer without a wireless card and I'd like to use the second airport extreme as a sort of wireless card for my extra computer.

Basically I've set up the second airport extreme to wirelessly extend the network, which works perfectly fine, but when I plug anything into the ethernet outlets of the second airport extreme they don't do anything. Is there a setting or option to enable the Ethernet ports on a wireless router that is wirelessly extending the range of a network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting the router it seems to be working now. Odd.